# Octane number definition differences in different countries

Tags: octane

In United States, I have understood that octane numbers are generally lower than in Europe for two reasons. Firstly, the gasoline is often genuinely lower-octane. Secondly, the numbers in United States don't mean the same thing as the numbers in Europe.

Why is there such a difference in the octane number scales? How can one convert between octane numbers in Europe and in United States?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to measure the octane number of a fuel. Europe uses the [RON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating#Measurement_methods) method.

> Research Octane Number (RON)
>
> The most common type of octane rating worldwide is the Research Octane Number (RON). RON is determined by running the fuel in a test engine with a variable compression ratio under controlled conditions, and comparing the results with those for mixtures of iso-octane and n-heptane.
>
> Motor Octane Number (MON)
>
> Another type of octane rating, called Motor Octane Number (MON), is determined at 900 rpm engine speed instead of the 600 rpm for RON.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating#Measurement_methods) MON testing uses a similar test engine to that used in RON testing, but with a preheated fuel mixture, higher engine speed, and variable ignition timing to further stress the fuel's knock resistance. Depending on the composition of the fuel, the MON of a modern pump gasoline will be about 8 to 12 octane lower than the RON, but there is no direct link between RON and MON. Pump gasoline specifications typically require both a minimum RON and a minimum MON.[citation needed]
>
> in Canada, the United States, Brazil, and some other countries, the headline number is the average of the RON and the MON, called the Anti-Knock Index (AKI), and often written on pumps as (R+M)/2). It may also sometimes be called the Posted Octane Number (PON).
>
> Difference between RON, MON, and AKI
>
> Because of the 8 to 12 octane number difference between RON and MON noted above, the AKI shown in Canada and the United States is 4 to 6 octane numbers lower than elsewhere in the world for the same fuel. This difference between RON and MON is known as the fuel's Sensitivity,[4] and is not typically published for those countries that use the Anti-Knock Index labelling system.

The Wikipedia article also contains a [conversion table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating#Examples).

Because there is no direct link between RON and MON (they're based on different measurements), there's no formula to calculate one from the other.